deriving a algebraic relation using the triangle inequality
I'm reading a textbook and I cannot figure out a step of the author. He has
the following:
$$ |y_{n_{k}}| \le y^{*}_{0} ~~ \forall k \ge 1 $$
$$ |y_{0}| \le y^{*}_{0} $$
He then states that the two inequalities above along with the triangle inequality lead
to
$$ (y_{0} - y_{n_{k}}) \le 4 (y^{*}_{0})^2 $$
Could someone show the details of how the last inequality is derived ? I know what the triangle equality says but I don't see how it leads to the last expression ? Thanks for the help.

Note $a-b\leq|a-b|\leq|a|+|-b|=|a|+|b|$.
So, $y_0-y_{n_k}\leq |y_0|+|y_{n_k}|\leq y_0^*+y_0^*=2y_0^*\leq 4(y_0^*)^2$ for $2y_0^*\geq 1$. I think there should be the constrain in the book, otherwise if $2y_0^*<1\implies 4(y_0^*)^2<2y_0^*$,

Thanks for your help. Maybe the author has a typo and  meant to have a square around the left hand side term in $(y_{0} - y_{n_{k}}) \le 4 (y^{*}_{0})^2 $. That would make your derivation perfect.

I will email the author so I'm checking your answer. I think it has to be a typo.
